# GridDB connection issue: 'No suitable driver found' error"

Tags: griddb

I'm trying to establish a connection to GridDB in my Java application, but I keep getting the 'No suitable driver found' error.

I have included the necessary GridDB JDBC driver in my project, but the error persists. I have also tried to add the GridDB JDBC driver JAR file to my project's classpath. I downloaded it from the official website and included it in my project's dependencies. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still seeing the error try the following as well:

1. Verify the JDBC driver version
2. Confirm the JAR file location - typically it should be in the classpath, directory like `lib` or `lib/ext` in your project's root directory
3. Check for conflicting drivers, if you have multiple JDBC drivers in your classpath
4. And even after all you still get error, please examine the error message, look for detailed stack trace for further discussion